# Differentiate between an empty cell and a cell which contains a formula

Tags: excel, vbscript

Is there a way in VBScript to check whether a cell is perceived to be empty (looks empty) but has a formula within it? Or rather how to check that the cell contains no other content but a formula within it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All formulas start with "=", so maybe you should try:

```
If Left(Cell.Formula, 1) = "=" And Cell.NumberFormat <> "@"
```

**Edit based on Dan's input...twice**

Comment: .Formula as opposed to .Text and this will do what you want. It will also work for Array formulas as the curly brackets are not really there. Where it could fail would be if you have a text field with = at the start, you could test the cell format to get around this

Comment: Instead of format = number maybe use not format = text ( or whatever the property for text is called) as you can have formulas formatted as things other than numbers :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the **Formula** Property of a Range Object?

For example:

put a formula in A1

> =IF(1=2,"YAY","")

```
    Sub Test
        Dim r as Range
        Set r = Cells(1,1)
        if r.Formula = "" then
         msgbox "No Formula In This Cell!"
        elseif r.Formula = "" and r.Value2= "" then
         msgbox "This cell is totally empty."
        end if

    End Sub
```

Comment: I tried translating your code above as a VBScript, however it does not seem to work.

Comment: @TeodoricoLevoff Are you using VBA within excel?. This code should work.

Comment: debug.print within a VBScript does not execute as intended.

Comment: @TeodoricoLevoff  You can eliminate the `debug.print` line and maybe replace with a message box. I've updated my answer with message box

Comment: If there is text in a cell (ie not a formula) r.Formula will return the text, this will fail your first if

Comment: @DanDonoghue I just tested this again. If there is a value in the cell, then `r.Formula`  =  "" in my system. Excel 2011. Alternatively, you could just be redundant in the IF statement: `If Left(r.Formula, 1) <> "=" Or r.Formula = "" Then`

Comment: @Gis You could use `If r.Formula = r.Value` if it's false then it's a formula, if it's true it's either text or empty. Unless the cell contains a formula that outputs itself, including the "=". Hopefully we can ignore such a situation.